# Can not import my custom typescript npm package

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, npm, export

I make a typescript npm package, simply like this:

#### Core.ts

```
class Core{
    constructor(){}
    //some functions
}
export = Core;
```

#### Core.d.ts

```
declare class Core {
   constructor(){}
   //some functions
}
export = Core;
```

#### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "@company/Core",
  "main": "dist/Core.js",
  "typings": "dist/Core" //.d.ts
  //etc
}
```

I make this module with webpack and ts-loader.

In my project, `index.ts`

```
import Core = require('@company/Core');
let core = new Core(); //Error, Core is not a function
```

I have tried to change `export` and `import` in some form but no luck. Do I miss some knowlage?

Comment: If `Core` isn't a function, what is it? Try `console.log(Core)` to see what you're actually getting from the `require` call.

Comment: is ```Object {}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solve my promble by myself. I add two properties in webpack configuration file, then recompile it and works well.

#### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
    }
    //etc
}
```